# Referencing same random value in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 functions I am calling form a SSRS dataset query:

- `fRndNumber()` returns a random value
- `fCheckSum()` returns a calculated value based in the value returned from `fRndNumber`.

The following statement does not work because the second call of `fRndNumber()` is generating a different value than the first call. I require the `fCheckSum` function to use the same value generated by `fRndNumber()`

```
Select 
    fRndNumber() as SerialNumber, 
    fCheckSum(fRndNumber) as CheckSum
```

Ideally I would like the statement to read as follows, but of course I cannot reference the 'SerialNumber' in this manner.

```
Select 
    fRndNumber() as SerialNumber, 
    fCheckSum(SerialNumber) as CheckSum
```

Any suggestions?

Doug P

Comment: Can you store fRndNumber() in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of SQL, you could use a CTE...

```
;WITH RandomCte AS
(
    SELECT  fRndNumber() AS SerialNumber,
            * -- add your other columns here...
    FROM    someTableName -- replace with your table name
)
SELECT  fCheckSum(SerialNumber) AS [CheckSum],
            *
FROM    RandomCte;
```

See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=SQL.105).aspx) for more info on CTEs

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTE is considered best practices these days. But if your server doesn't support them, you could also use an inline view:

```
SELECT
  A.SerialNumber,
  fCheckSum(A.SerialNumber) AS CheckSum
FROM  (
 SELECT fRndNumber() as SerialNumber
) as A;
```

Comment: Thanks Scott and Sam.  Sam's suggestion is something I am comfortable with implementing and will work perfectly for me.